# Деление строки на массив

Tags: javascript

Создать одно окно в котором ты можешь вводить строку, пример:

```
3+5
3-5
3*5
3/5
```

После нажимаешь на результат и в результате выдаешь отдельно на каждой строчке:

```
3
+
5
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Моя попытка)

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.input');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const show = document.querySelector('.show');



btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  const values = input.value.split('');
  let operator = null;
  let result = null;
  for (const symbol of values) {
    if (symbol === '+' || symbol === '-' || symbol === '*' || symbol === '/') {
      operator = symbol;
    }
  }
  result = show.innerHTML = `${values[0]}<br>${operator}<br>${values[2]}`
})
```

```html
  <input type="text" class="input">
  <button class="btn">Show Results</button>
  <div class="show"></div>
```

Comment: о) мне тоже прилетелетело)

Comment: мне и вопросу второй))

Answer (score -1):

Так подойдёт или надо чтобы значения вычислялись?

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#exressions');
const calculate = document.querySelector('#calculate');
const results = document.querySelector('#results');

calculate.addEventListener('click', () => {
  results.innerHTML = '';
  
  input.value.split(' ').forEach(expression => {
    const expressionLine = document.createElement('p');
    
    expressionLine.innerHTML = `${expression} =`;
    
    results.append(expressionLine);
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="exressions"/>
<button id="calculate">Show Results</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Что? Дополнительный знак равенства не удовлетворил?) (Обращение к минусуещему)

Comment: так вроде работает не так как нужно автору?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолмак Ну после того как модератор поправил вопрос, то, конечно, не работает как надо)) Я же писал ответ для изначального вопроса) По истории изменений если глянете, то поймёте, почему я такой ответ оставил. Я просто жду, когда вопрошающий скажет что-то на счёт моего решения, чтобы я поправил как надо

Comment: ах вот оно что) я так и подумал) в итоге